# Double INSERT using a TRANSACTION postgres

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

Good evening,

I want to create a TRANSACTION with the proper isolation level. On that transaction I want to do a double insert and if one fails the other one is aborted.

I have a stored procedure already created:

```
create or replace function insert_into_answercomments(userid INTEGER, answerid INTEGER, body text)
  returns void language plpgsql as $$
DECLARE result INTEGER;
  insert into publications(body, userid)
  VALUES (body, userid)
  returning publications.publicationid AS publicationid INTO result;

  insert into comments(publicationid) VALUES (result);

  insert into answercomments(commentid, answerid) VALUES (result, answerid);
end $$;
```

My doubt is if the transaction should be inside the function or if it is a different procedure. How do I create it with a correct isolation level.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transaction cannot be started/ended inside postgres function. If you want some logic, make it inside function. In your case you don't need anything - if first insert generates exception, transaction aborts. But if you need some sophisticated check, make it right in code, eg

```
if result > 90 then
  insert ...second insert
end if;
```

to run function in transaction start it outside, eg:

```
begin;
select * from insert_into_answercomments(1,2);
end;
```

Comment: But how would I call that transaction? Any time I needed to make those double inserts how would I call the transaction if its not a procedure?

Comment: ```begin;
select * from insert_into_answercomments(1,2);
end;```

Comment: Thank you. What about isolation level? Do you have any idea whats the level? How do I declare it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html In your case READ COMMITTED is enough

Comment: @LuísCosta did I answer your question?

Comment: You did! Thank you so much!
Not to bother you, could you please tell me why you conside `READ COMMITED` is enough?

Comment: becase if you run it in transaction, no one will see your half inserts. And you don't select anything at all :)